# Cut and paste entire Excel column

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm looking for some sample code on how to **cut** and paste an entire column in Excel.

Comment: Umm.. to the person who voted to close because my question is off topic... can you elaborate why you think this is off-topic? I'm looking for VSTO code...!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it there's a reason it takes more than one vote

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to cut and paste a range, then just specify the range using the column letter.  eg. `Range("A:A")` specifies the whole of column A.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [sample](http://malick.blog.com/2010/01/15/cut-an-paste-rows-in-excel-using-vsto-c/)  the cuts and pastes a row. Converting it to a column should be trivial

Comment: Actually I was looking into that post before I decided to ask everyone on SO! OK, I'll review it again (...more carefully this time).

Answer (score 0):

My first question is - do you have to read from an Excel file? Is it possible, export to a CSV or something else. This may be easier.

Otherwise, you can do something like this (assuming you already have the reference to the Excel object):

```
xlobj.workbook("workbook1.xls").sheets("Sheet1").Columns("C:C").Cut
xlobj.workbook("workbook1.xls").sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A").Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)

```
Application app = new Application();
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open("test.xlsx");
Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets["MyTestSheet"];
Range rngSource = ws.UsedRange.Columns["A"];
Range rngTarget = ws.UsedRange.Columns["D"];
rngTarget.Value = rngSource.Value;
rngSource.Value = null;
wb.Save();
app.Application.Quit();
```

You can do the same with fewer lines of code, but for demonstration purposes I've written it that way. Bear in mind that the above code violates the "Never use 2 dots when referring to COM objects", which might cause trouble disposing the COM objects and leave zombie Excel processes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'EntireColumn' property, that's what it is there for:

```
string rangeQuery = "A1:A1";

Range range = workSheet.get_Range(rangeQuery, Type.Missing);

range = range.EntireColumn;
```

Comment: My question, was how to *cut* an entire column. I know how to grab a column, LOL.