# Cut and Paste Columns in Excel Range with c#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to move column B in front of column Q in an excel sheet as part of a report I'm working on. I have experience in VBA but relatively little in c# so I've spent the last hour on Google and can't find a solution, I feel like this should be simple but I can't quite get it.

Method one, which results in a “Insert method of Range class failed” msg.

```
Excel.Range rngCut1 = JobLabourSheet.get_Range("B:B", Type.Missing);
Excel.Range rngPaste1 = JobLabourSheet.get_Range("Q:Q", Type.Missing);
            rngCut1.Columns.Cut(rngPaste1.EntireColumn.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, rngCut1));
```

Method two results in a “Unable to get a Cut property of the Range class” msg.

```
Excel.Range rngCut1 = JobLabourSheet.get_Range("B:B", Type.Missing);
Excel.Range rngPaste1 = JobLabourSheet.get_Range("Q:Q", Type.Missing);
            rngCut1.Columns.Cut(rngPaste1.EntireColumn.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, Missing.Value));
```

In the second method when I omit the CopyOrigin I get the msg but it does insert a blank column in front of column Q.

In VBA I would use the following:

```
Columns("B:B").Cut
Columns("Q:Q").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

But like I said, my c# experience is limited at the moment so I have no idea how to go about translating it to c#

Comment: Take a look at [Used Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cut and paste entire Excel column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877749/cut-and-paste-entire-excel-column)

Comment: @Ken White, I did look at that post but couldn't make the anwers work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't very intuitive, but this is how I got it to work. I took an "insert" range and used the Insert() method and passed a "range.Cut()" method as the "Copy Origin" parameter.

Reference docs:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.insert.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlinsertshiftdirection.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.cut.aspx

Here is a sample app (be sure to add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelCutAndInsertColumn
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\stackoverflow.xlsx");
            Excel.Worksheet xlWs = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWb.Sheets[1]; // Sheet1

            xlApp.Visible = true;

            // cut column B and insert into A, shifting columns right
            Excel.Range copyRange = xlWs.Range["B:B"];
            Excel.Range insertRange = xlWs.Range["A:A"];

            insertRange.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, copyRange.Cut());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, I tried you're method and it works but not quite how I need it to. Using rngCut1.Cut(rngPaste1); cuts it from column B (it leaves column B blank) and pastes it into column Q. However, it overwrites the values in column Q. What I need it to do is insert ShiftToRight.

Comment: @Cornelius Got it. I figured something out. Will edit answer now.