# Change position of Columns In Excel file using C#

Tags: c#

**Hello**,

I'm Using Microsoft.Office.Interop in C#. Is there any easy way to change the columns position of the Excel worksheet.

Example: 
The position of the first column is 1.
The position of the second column is 2.
.
.
.
The position of the tenth column is 10.

**What i need is to change this position, Example :**
The position of the first column into 5.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cut and Paste Columns in Excel Range with c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870310/cut-and-paste-columns-in-excel-range-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks moritzpflaum this solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This..

// Cut column c and insert into A, shifting columns right

```
    Excel.Range copyRange = xlWs.Range["C:C"];
    Excel.Range insertRange = xlWs.Range["A:A"];
    insertRange.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, copyRange.Cut());
```