# Copy specific columns from one excel spreadsheet to another in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have been trying to make a simple app to merge information from one excel spreadsheet to another in c#. But I don't find any reference about how could I do this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtgZR.jpg)

I have the info in one spreadsheet and I need to copy that information in another spreadsheet file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVJ4q.jpg)

How can do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2603625/1706578

Comment: Or if you'd like to use the Excel interop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870310/cut-and-paste-columns-in-excel-range-with-c-sharp

Comment: Let me check them out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another thing you may want to try out (the code uses [GemBox.Spreadsheet library](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview)):

```
ExcelFile source = ExcelFile.Load("Source.xlsx");
ExcelColumn sourceColumn = source.Worksheets[0].Columns[0];

ExcelFile destination = ExcelFile.Load("Destination.xlsx");
ExcelColumn destinationColumn = destination.Worksheets[0].Columns[0];

int count = source.Worksheets[0].Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    destinationColumn.Cells[i].Value = sourceColumn.Cells[i].Value;

destination.Save("Destination.xlsx");
```