# How to cut a range of cells using Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel

I have a column and i'm looking to cut rows 3-37 and move it to the column directly to the right of it.

I tried the following and it moves the values correctly to the right but the cell styles don't copy over.

```
Range copyRange = ws1.Range["L5:L37"];
Range insertRange = ws1.Range["M5:M37"];
insertRange = copyRange;
```

I've also tried solution from here [Cut and Paste Columns in Excel Range with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870310/cut-and-paste-columns-in-excel-range-with-c-sharp) but nothing seem to copy

```
Range copyRange = ws1.Range["L5:L37"];
Range insertRange = ws1.Range["M5:M37"];
//insertRange.Insert(copyRange.Cut());
insertRange.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, copyRange.Cut());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just replace the contents of the destination cells with the contents of the source cells, and delete the contents of the source cells, then the [`Range.Cut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.cut.aspx) method ought to do the trick if you call it with the destination range as an argument:

```
Range sourceRange = ws1.Range["L5:L37"];
Range destinationRange = ws1.Range["M5:M37"];
sourceRange.Cut(destinationRange);
```

This will *not* copy `sourceRange` to the clipboard, but it *will* clear the clipboard if you already have a range on the clipboard.

You can also specify only the upper left cell of the destination range, and it will do the same thing:

```
Range sourceRange = ws1.Range["L5:L37"];
Range destinationRange = ws1.Range["M5"];
sourceRange.Cut(destinationRange);
```

If you want to keep the contents of the source cells, use `Copy` instead of `Cut`.

(Note that the statement `insertRange = copyRange;` definitely should *never* copy any cells anywhere if `insertRange` is a local variable. That could only happen if C# supported overloaded assignment (which, to my knowledge, it does not) or if some other code somehow "sensed" the assignment.)